# Python: How to convert string of an encoded Unicode variable to a binary variable

Tags: python, string, unicode, binary, hex

I am building an app to transliterate Myanmar (Burmese) text to International Phonetic Alphabet. I have found that it's easier to manipulate combining Unicode characters in my dictionaries as binary variables like this

```
b'\xe1\x80\xad\xe1\x80\xaf\xe1\x80\x84': 'áɪŋ̃',    #'ိုင'
```

because otherwise they glue to neighboring characters like apostrophes and I can't get them unstuck.
I am translating UTF-8 Burmese characters to binary hex variables to build my dictionaries. Sometimes I want to convert backwards. I wrote a simple program:

```
while True:
    binary = input("Enter binary Unicode string or 'exit' to exit: ")
    if binary == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        print(binary.decode('utf-8'))
```

Obviously this will not work for an input such as `b'\xe1\x80\xad'`, since input() returns a string.
I would like to know the quickest way to convert the string `"b'\xe1\x80\xad'"` to it's Unicode form '  ိ '. My only idea is

```
binary = bin(int(binary, 16))
```

but that returns

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: "b'\\xe1\\x80\\xad\\'"
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Personally, rather than trying to transcode byte sequences, I'd build an table using ICU transform rules then run through a transliterate command in PyICU, and it may be worth checking to see if anyone has already written a set of transform rules for Burmese/Myanmar IPA.

Comment: I assume you've implemented word segmentation before converting to bytes for transliterating into IPA?

Comment: Burmese pronunciation is based on individual syllable structure. There are thousands of syllables possible and finding the end of one syllable and the beginning of the next is no easy task. I wrote a 540 line script that tries to do the job. I hope to finish it and post it on GitHub.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyICU. I appreciate your recommendation. I want to finish this project since it has personal significance for me. However, if someone has already done it, I would like to know.

Comment: I am aware of the challenges. And since you are converting to IPA you need to convert phonemic syllables rather than orthographic syllables, which adds to the complexity. Most existing Myanmar syllabic segmentation solutions are based on orthographic syllables.

Comment: I have a few contacts who have worked on or are working on Myanmar NLP including text to speech applications, so will ask around.

Comment: Both CLDR and ICU have a my_my_FONIPA mapping (Burmese to IPA) but it is only in one direction, not reversible. Will ask around for reversible solutions.

Comment: As you indicated conversion of Myanmar to IPA needs to be at syllable level, i.e. ခါ -> /kʰà/, ခါး -> /kʰá/, ခ -> /kʰa̰/, ခတ် -> /kʰæʔ/, ခံ -> /kʰæ̀ɰ̃/, ခန်း -> /kʰǽɰ̃/, ခန့် -> /kʰæ̰ɰ̃/.  But first step is word segmentation then within a polysyllabic word syllable segmentation. Since the IPA representation would need to be word segmented.

Comment: I used an algorithm. It looks for syllable ending characters like punctuation, numbers, and spaces. It looks for virama to signal that a second consonant is part of the previous syllable. It looks for three consonants in a row, marking that at least the first consonant's syllable is complete. I used an object called Buffer to store the syllables as they were scanned. I will post my code to GitHub soon. It has too many print statements right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254034/discussion-between-deersfeet-and-andj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the input string "b'\xe1\x80\xad'" is not a valid hexadecimal string that can be converted to Unicode directly. However, you can use the ast module to safely evaluate the string as a Python literal and get the corresponding bytes object. Here's an example:

```py
import ast

binary = "b'\\xe1\\x80\\xad'"
bytes_obj = ast.literal_eval(binary)
unicode_str = bytes_obj.decode('utf-8')
print(unicode_str)
```

This should output the Unicode character 'ိ'. The ast.literal_eval() function safely evaluates the input string as a Python literal, which in this case is a bytes object. You can then decode the bytes object to get the corresponding Unicode string.

Comment: Thank you!!
What exactly *is* b'\xe1\x80\xad'? Just a binary variable of a string of a hexadecimal number?